# Is there an interface to access pyproject.toml from Python?

Tags: python, python-importlib, toml, pyproject.toml

Is there an interface to access the information in pyproject.toml from Python?

In particular, I'd like to access the dependencies. It doesn't seem hard to do

```py
toml.load("pyproject.toml")['project']['dependencies']
```

and then parse that list. But that would be rewriting logic that must already be available somewhere.

Apparently there is `importlib.metadata.requires()`, which would be better than the line above, but that seems to give a similar list of strings that still requires manual parsing:

```
>>> metadata.requires("scipy")
['numpy<1.27.0,>=1.19.5', 'pytest; extra == "test"', ...
```

(As for the XY problem, I was thinking about writing a test that tries to install a package with the lowest versions of its dependencies to see whether the package still works.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, whether project metadata (such as dependency requirements) is obtained from [`pyproject.toml`'s standardized `[project]` section](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/) or via [`importlib.metadata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html) the values should be the same. At least, as far as I know, the dependency requirements have the same format.

Probably I would use the 3rd party [*packaging*](https://pypi.org/project/packaging/) library, in particular its [`packaging.requirements.Requirement()`](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/stable/requirements.html), to parse the dependency requirements. This library can handle other values of project metadata as well, read the documentation. As far as I know this is the library that *pip* itself uses internally (so it should be always reliable and up-to-date).

The issue with obtaining project metadata from `pyproject.toml`, is that some fields can be declared [*dynamic*](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/#dynamic). Which means their value is not set in `pyproject.toml`.

If you are fine with that, then the TOML parser from Python's standard library [*tomllib*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tomllib.html) could be good enough. You could also give [*pyproject-parser*](https://pypi.org/project/pyproject-parser/) a try, it seems like a correct and reliable library.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. So the best way to access the info in `pyproject.toml` is usually not to access it directly, but to use `importlib.metadata` and `packaging`.

Comment: What do you want to do? Reading from `pyproject.toml` or from `importlib.metadata` is not the same use case. `importlib.metadata` is for reading packaging metadata of libraries that are already installed. Reading from `pyproject.toml` is for reading from source code directory (or eventually, maybe from *sdist*), it means libraries that are not installed (yet).

Comment: For my immediate goals, either directly reading `pyproject.toml` or using `importlib.metadata` would suffice. The transition from `setup.py` to `pyproject.toml` makes it easier to retrieve information about how the installed package will look without actually installing it, so I was looking for an elegant way to explore that idea. But for now I'd be happy to either install the package first, or to manually read the toml file.

Comment: OK, then the TOML parser from Python's standard library and the 3rd party *packaging* library should be more than good enough. -- You could also give [*pyproject-parser*](https://pypi.org/project/pyproject-parser/) a try, I have not tried it myself, but the author/maintainer is active in the packaging community and personally I would trust this library to be reliable and correct. -- The issue with relying on `pyproject.toml` only is that some fields can be [*dynamic*](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/#dynamic).

Answer (score 1):

My solution requires to have the package installed. You can install them via `--editable` in *Development Mode* if you need. I try to avoid dependencies and use the `importlib.metadata` to extract and convert the packages metadata into a dictionary. Then I set global package variables like `__version__` with values from that dictionary.

This is part of my packages `__init__.py`

```
from collections import Counter
from importlib.metadata import metadata

def _package_metadata_as_dict() -> dict:
    """Get package metadata and return it as a dict."""

    m = metadata(__name__)

    result = {}

    for key, count in Counter(m.keys()).items():

        if key in exclude_keys:
            continue

        # single value key
        if count == 1:
            result[key] = m[key]
            continue

        # multi value key
        result[key] = []
        for val in m.get_all(key):
            result[key].append(val)

    # postprocess project URLs
    urls = result['Project-URL']
    result['Project-URL'] = {}
    for entry in urls:
        key, val = entry.split(',')
        result['Project-URL'][key.strip()] = val.strip()

    return result


meta = _package_metadata_as_dict()

__version__ = meta['Version']
"""Version string of the package."""

__name__ = meta['Name']
"""Vanila name of that package."""
```

The object returned by `importlib.metadata.metadata()` is somehow awkward for me. But I'm sure there is a professional design decision behind it and I just don't get it. That is why I need that much code to convert it into a `dict`.